# Kubernetes service pointing to specific instance of ReplicaSet

Tags: kubernetes, service, port, kubernetes-service

I have a pretty strange use-case in which we need to have multiple concurrent connections to the same `ReplicaSet` but each one of them needs to go to a different instance.

Here's an image to summarize it:

[image]

Is there any way to set a `label` based on the `ordinal index` of an instance in the replica set?
In that way I could map different ports to different instances.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like it will require special handling via the Ingress controller you are using; please do consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63565901/edit) to include what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Assuming http based cookies something that are looking for you can use ingress controller and so called `sticky sessions` / `session affinity`.

> The ingress controller replies the response with a Set-Cookie header
> to the first request. The value of the cookie will map to a specific
> pod replica. When the subsequent request come back again, the client
> browser will attach the cookie and the ingress controller is therefore
> able to route the traffic to the same pod replica.

Basically by setting appropriate annotations in the ingress object, you will make sure the subsequent traffic request will still be sent to the same pod.

Nginx has a [good example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/ingress.yaml) and [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/#sticky-sessions) about those.

Alternatively you can also use [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/services/#sticky-sessions) as ingress controllers. It also supports sitcky session (they`re just defined not at ingress level but traefik's ingressroute).